# nginx load balancer

Tags: linux, nginx, devops

Всем добрый день.
Есть сервер с Tomcat и отдельно nginx сервер. В настройка в location указываешь proxy_pass на tomcat сервер то без проблем работает а если в upstream как балансирвоку указываешь то пишет bad_request.

```
upstream web_backend {
        server 1.1.1.1;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1;
        }
```

Comment: Покажите нормально обе конфигурации, а не непонятного кадавра

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Я даже не буду пытаться читать конфиг nginx в одну строчку в комментариях

Comment: Не вижу варианта с использованием web_backend

Comment: Да, если проксировать на 1 сервер то нет смысла в этом. Просто без upstream то работает в если сервер вынести в upstream то не работает. Почему?

Comment: посмотрите тут - https://nick.zoic.org/art/nginx-django-400-bad-request/